# Question regarding the sequence definition of continuity.

Tags: limits, continuity

Here is an excerpt from Ross' Elementary Analysis (specifically the definition of continuity): "The function $f$ is $\it \space continuous\space  at \space x_0$ if, for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $dom(f)$ converging to $x_0$, we have $lim_nf(x_n)=f(x_0)$."
My question is the subscript in the limit needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, it is needed. I prefer to write: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0).$$

Comment: See my confusion started because earlier in the text he stated that if the limit is simply written as $lim$, then it is implied the limit goes to infinity.  I didn't think he would write it alternatively.